# Strip html tags in css tooltip

Tags: css

I am trying to create a tooltip for my site that gets data from MySQL. everything is working fine but it displays html tags. data is stored in MySQL using tinymce so it does not strip the tags when entered nor I want it to, However I would like it to strip it in the tooltip.

This is my code and screenshot

Thanks in advance.

```
.tooltip span {
z-index:10;
display:none; 
padding:8px 8px;
margin-top:23px;
width:260px;
max-width:260px; 
max-height:260px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
color:#ffffff;
overflow:hidden;  
}

.tooltip:hover span{
display:inline; 
position:absolute;  
color:#ffffff;
background:#2588b3;
text-decoration:none;    
}

.tooltip:focus span{
display:inline; 
position:absolute;  
color:#ffffff;
background:#2588b3;
text-decoration:none;     
}
```

Screenshot with text only

[image]

Screenshot with image and links

[image]

How can I strip the images and links just from the tooltip? I've tried text-decoration but that did nothing.

Thanks once again.

Comment: Erm - you CAN'T do this in CSS. CSS is for styling.. not for manipulating... you'll need some JS to manipulate the DOM..

Comment: What language creates the tooltips, PHP? Strip it there.

Comment: This isn't a CSS question, you need to do this in your tooltip creation code.

Comment: Downvote for clear lack of research....

Comment: This is the code I am using in html. <td class="olotd4 tooltip"> <span>{$customer_work_orders_result[i].WORK_ORDER_DESCRIPTION}</span>{$customer_work_orders_result[i].WORK_ORDER_SCOPE}</td>

Comment: @stuart sklinar, css is not my best so sorry for getting you off on the wrong side..

Comment: Don't worry - but CSS can't do anything. just makes things look pretty.

Comment: I seems to have some issues stripping it within a span. any suggestions?

Comment: Just an fyi...I was able to use |strip_tags:true within smarty element!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by writing my own modifier:

save it as smarty/plugins/modifier.strip_tags_exclude.php (or in your custom plugins folder)
function smarty_modifier_strip_tags_exclude()
{

```
$params=func_get_args();

if (!isset($params[1])) {
    $params[1] = true;
}
if ($params[1] === true) {
    return preg_replace('!<[^>]*?>!', ' ', $params[0]);
} else {
    if (is_string($params[1]))
    {
        $allowable_tags = strtr($params[1],'[]','<>');
    }


    return strip_tags($params[0],$allowable_tags);
}
```

}

and then you can use it this way:
{$variable|strip_tags_exclude:'

'}

or alternatively (some editors may get confused and think that you're opening tags):
{$variable|strip_tags_exclude:'[a][p][ul][li]'}